# Simple currency conversion script not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a simple javascript currency convertion app. Thing is it just won't work no mather how much I tinker with it. 
The input fields don't accept any input and only show "0" when trying to enter any numbers.

I tought the PHP code might be the problem at first, but apparently it should run with no problem.

```
<h1 style='font-size:46px'>1 DOLLAR = <input readonly id="currentprice" type="number">
<?php $url = "https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD"; 
    $json = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true); 
    $price = $json_data["rates"]["BRL"]; 

    echo $price; 
 ?> 
    />
</h1>

How many Dollars?
<input oninput='finalAmountUSD()' onchange='finalAmountUSD()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number' class="buy buyinput form-control" id='usdamount' required value='0.00000000' tabindex="1" />
How many BRL?
<input oninput='finalAmountBRL()' onchange='finalAmountBRL()' style='font-size:23px;height:45px' type='number' class="buy buyinput form-control" id='brlamount' required value='0.00' tabindex="2" />

<script>
    function finalAmountUSD() {
        x = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;
        y = document.getElementById('usdamount').value;
        z = document.getElementById('brlamount').value;

        document.getElementById('usdamount').value = x * z;
    }
    function finalAmountBRL() {
        x = document.getElementById('currentprice').value;
        y = document.getElementById('usdamount').value;
        z = document.getElementById('brlamount').value;

        document.getElementById('brlamount').value = x * y;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A p element does not have a `value`, `value` is for input elements. Nor do they have a `type`.

Comment: all inputs from a form are strings/text. You need to convert them to numbers i.e. var x = parseInt( document.getElementById('currentprice').value ); You also need to change document.getElementById('usdamount').value = x * z; to document.getElementById('usdamount').innerHTML = x * z;

Comment: @RonnieOosting he is trying to do currency conversion not just format the number as currency based on a specific locale

Comment: @AndyG I changed it to a readonly input, but still won't work.

Comment: Are there errors in your browser's console? And, yes, you need to convert the string values to numbers.

Comment: @jeff I did as you sugested. Now I can input values, but the other field will not update with the conversion rate.

Comment: I don't see how the PHP tag is relevant here

Answer (score 0):

You are using two events handlers oninput and onchange. The oninput event handler is fired right after the value of the element changes, while the onchange event handler is fired when the element's value changes and the element loses focus.

I think you only need the oninput event handler.